# TypeError csv.reader through a List

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

I create a list of filename titled "dict1".  See a sample of the error message for what the list looks like.

Then I want to read through each filename in "dict1" until all have been processed.

```
# creates dict each containing 5 file names to be processed.
list = open("/opt/stateadm/AAM_Scripts/Realtime/file.txt").read()
list_words = list.split('\n')
dict1 = ('\n'.join(list_words[0:5]))
print dict1
# for each row in dict (file) open read and publish to Redis
for row in dict1:
    dir = '/opt/stateadm/AAM_Scripts/Realtime/outgoing/traits/'
    reader = csv.reader(open(dir + dict1(row)))
    header = reader.next()
    client = redis.StrictRedis(host='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', port=6379, db=0)
    client1 = redis.StrictRedis(host='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', port=6379, db=0)
    client2 = redis.StrictRedis(host='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', port=6379, db=0)
    list1 =(client, client1, client2)
    for row in reader:
        key = 'AAM_CDF_Traits'
        doc = dict(zip(header, row))
        random.choice(list1).publish(key, doc)
```

Error Message:

```
print dict1
split_bj.csv
split_bi.csv
split_bh.csv
split_bg.csv
split_bf.csv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./AAM_Redis6.sh", line 32, in <module>
    reader = csv.reader(open(dir + dict1(row)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am not sure why I am getting that error.  I just want to "append" the directory to each "row"(filename) in Dict1 and read through each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict1` is a single string, not a list or dictionary. You are trying to use it as a function with `dict1(row)`.

You probably just want to loop over the original list instead:

```
for row in list_words[0:5]:
    reader = csv.reader(open(dir + row))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I see why I was getting that error.  Thank you for explaining.